# Serialize data in AJax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I having trouble for adding a multiple Sub Author in my form, I have a form that you can add a sub author. The code works if I only submit one sub author but if multiple sub author the codes not working. 
Here's the code of my text box in FormAddBook.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sub Authors" name="SubAuthors[]"  maxlength="50" />
```

And when you want to add another sub author, text box will appear when yun click the Add Sub Author with the same name of textbox.

The codes work when one sub author only but if multiple sub authors the codes not working. 
Here's the code of my jquery.

```
$.ajax({ 
      type: 'POST', 
      url: 'proc/exec/exec-insert-book.php',
      data: $('#FormAddBook').serialize(), 
});
```

Does the Serialize cannot recognize the another text box?

 Sorry for my bad english.

 Here's the HTML Form code.

```
  <form id="FormAddBook">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6 hide" >
            <label>Accession No:</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Accession No" name="AccessionNo" readonly/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>ISBN:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ISBN" name="BookISBN"  maxlength="20" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date Book Added:</label>
                <div  id="DateBookAdded" class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Book Added" name="DateBookAdded" readonly/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Archived Date Extension:</label>
                <div  id="BookAuthLast" class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="ArchivedDateExt" readonly/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="subauthcont">
        <div class="subAuthors col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Sub authors:</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sub Authors" name="SubAuthors[]"  maxlength="50" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn" disabled>
                        <button id="btnAddSubAuth" class="btn btn-info" type="button" ><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Subject:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="Description">
                    <option>Generalities</option>
                    <option>Philosophy and Psychology</option>
                    <option>Religion</option>
                    <option>Social Science</option>
                    <option>Languages</option>
                    <option>Science</option>
                    <option>Technology</option>
                    <option>Arts and Recreation</option>
                    <option>Literature</option>
                    <option>Geography and History</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Status:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="Status" readonly>
                    <option>Available</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button id="btnSave2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary asd">Save</button>

  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: paste your full `[HTML]` form code.

Comment: <div id="subauthcont">
         <div class="subAuthors col-lg-12">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>Sub authors:</label>
              <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sub Authors" name="SubAuthors[]"  maxlength="50" />
      <span class="input-group-btn" disabled>
             <button id="btnAddSubAuth" class="btn btn-info" type="button" ><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
           </span>
     </div> 
    </div>
      </div>
         </div>

Comment: Not in comment, Edit your question and update it.

Comment: can't paste here the full code.

Comment: I've been update the question.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Error doesn't show.